# What is the meaning of 'Let' in a com interface?

Tags: pdf-generation, com-interface

This might be a really stupid question - I am new to com-interface. I couldn't find any information by googling ("let" is too common a word).

I am trying to automate PDF creation by calling the PDFCreator COM interface via the Jacob-library.

I am reading the API on the the [PDFCreator website](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/clspdfcreator), and see:

```
Public Property Let cOptionProfile(ByVal ProfileName As String, ByVal PropertyName As String, ByVal value As Variant)
Public Property Get cOptions() As clsPDFCreatorOptions
Public Property Set cOptions(ByVal Options1 As clsPDFCreatorOptions)
```

What is the meaning of "Let"? Are these just typos and supposed to mean "Set"?

Thanks for your help.